# Handling a framework-specific event and MVVM?

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns, mvvm

In a WPF application that uses Prism, I have a shell in which there is a docking manager control.

Now I have to listen to an event coming from that docking manager, specifically, when one of its children docking state has changed.

To me, this event should be handled in code-behind as letting the view model do some work against that framework-specific visual control is worse than doing it code-behind.

**Question:**

Is this the right approach or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the code is only related for the presentation then it is no problem to have it in "code-behind".

The main problem with "code-behind" is having the presentation logic split in two different locations XAML and "code-behind". There are several ways to avoid that using [`MarkupExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.markupextension?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), DependencyProperty, ValueConverter or custom (derived) controls.

Comment: Already forgot about that, I've opted for `Interaction.Behaviors`, thank you!